# google realtime api / drive api -> get user role for realtime doc

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api, google-realtime-api

I have a realtime app and get the collaborators with `doc.getCollaborators()` and this gives me an array [] `doc` is from the type `gapi.drive.realtime.Document`:

[image]

According to the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.Document) there is no field like `isOwner` that shows me if the current collaborator is the owner of the realtime document "`doc`"

My Question how can I find out which role the collaborators of a `doc` has.
In the API documentation I find: "The Realtime API supports owner, reader and writer roles"

If I try to use `gapi.client.drive.permissions.list` suggested from the [google drive api reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/list):

```
    function retrievePermissions(fileId, callback) {
        var request = gapi.client.drive.permissions.list({
            'fileId': fileId
        });
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            callback(resp.items);
        });
    }


    retrievePermissions(self.realtimeDocId, function (resp) {
        resp;


        });
```

Then I get the following error message:

> Error in Realtime load callback: TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'permissions' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'permissions' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

To use the drive API you must load it separately from the Realtime API.

```
window.gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function ()
{
    // Run your code here.
});
```

After getting the permissions list, you can use the permissions ID for each user returned from your RealtimeDoc::getCollaborators call.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check how you've place your codes, based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/drive), you can integrate Realtime API to the Drive platform.

> Realtime documents are attached to files stored in Google Drive. Accordingly, your application should use the [Drive REST API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/) to interact with Drive files. For example, to create a new file, use the [**`files.insert`**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) method from the Drive REST API. To retrieve a file that already exists, use the [**`files.get`**](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) method.
>
> For more information on interacting with files in Google Drive, see [Google Drive Integration](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/drive).

As for code implementation you can check [CodeMirror Collaboration with Google Drive Realtime Api](https://github.com/jonasfj/google-drive-realtime-examples).

Drive API:

```
/**
 * Creates a new Realtime file.
 * @param title {string} title of the newly created file.
 * @param callback {Function} the callback to call after creation.
 */
rtclient.createRealtimeFile = function(title, callback) {
  gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', function() {
    gapi.client.drive.files.insert({
      'resource': {
        mimeType: rtclient.REALTIME_MIMETYPE,
        title: title
      }
    }).execute(callback);
  });
}
```

For Realtime API:

```
// We have a file ID in the query parameters, so we will use it to load a file.
  if (fileId) {
    gapi.drive.realtime.load(fileId, this.onFileLoaded, this.initializeModel, handleErrors);
    return;
  }
```

Hope this info helps.